# prevent duplicate publishing of watch action on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish

I have successfully implemented Facebook watch action on my website. The problem is that every time I open a particular video, depending on how many times I do it, it records each of these as separate watch actions. I would like to record the watch action only once for each unique video. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

1) Check in your own database to see if you've already published that action against that object and simply don't post it twice - you'll already be logging this because it's necessary to store the action instance IDs to remove the watch actions later if the user requests you to

2) Set the action as unique in the OG settings for the action. This may not apply to built-in actions, i'm not 100% sure, but in the general case you can mark an action as 'unique' and it'll only be possible to publish once per action/object combo for a user

Comment: where do i mark the action as unique? Under which config page? am not using a db to store the publish ids.thnx.

Comment: You **need** to track all your publishes, or you won't be able to get the action approved by Facebook because you won't be able to meet most of the requirements for watch action approvals at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch